# Decomposing big member function

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, coding-style, class-design

## Decomposing a member function

In a class there is a member function that is rather long. Let's say we have

```
class Customer {
public:
        void process();

...
};
```

The method *process* is by nature long and consists of a couple of different
steps. You'd like these steps to be functions of their own, to avoid having
multiple levels of abstraction in the process method. I have thought of these
different options (including the noop-alternative):

#### Create stand-alone functions for the steps outside of the class.

```
double step_a(vector<Order> orders, double foo);
void step_b(double bar);

void Customer::proccess()
{
        double foo;
        ...
        double bar = step_a(this->orders, foo);
        ...
        step_b(bar);
};
```

Concerns: The class is less self-contained. The stand alone functions are so
specific to the process function that they would never be of interest to any
other code, making it feel unnatural to keep them outside of the class.

#### Create private methods.

```
class Customer {
public:
        void process();
private:
        double step_a(double foo);
        void step_b(double bar);
};
```

Concerns: The private methods for the steps (at least some of them) wouldn't
operate on any class members at all. They have no side effects, they only
compute a value from arguments and return it, so they have no need at all to
be member functions of the class.

#### Leave Customer::process as is

Concerns: The function becomes long, and could be hard to read, because of all
the details in the steps making it hard to see the big picture of what steps
the process contains.

### Question:

### What would be the cleanest way to handle this?

(Perhaps none of the above, but someting I hadn't thought of.)

Comment: I would suggest following SOLID programming principles, with taking specific note to tje Single Responsibility principle.

Comment: Please, elaborate on how that resolves the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't really language agnostic. Not all languages have stand alone functions.
In C++ or C# I would probably use private member functions (static if possible).

In C++ you could use stand-alone functions (possibly in an anonymous namespace) so they are not visible to the outside.

Comment: Static private function seems reasonable. Do you agree with my concerns of the options I listen, do you have more thoughts about this?

Comment: Many, many languages have classes and stand-alone functions. Even if they don't have stand-alone functions, two of my listen alternatives are still valid. Wouldn't very few questions would be language-agnostic if they have to apply equallt to all languages? I mean there's always Brainfuck...

Comment: @Joel - Re your concerns: I see no problem with specific stand-alone functions, as long as they are invisible to the outside. Possibly by using anonymous namespace to avoid linker problems, in case other code uses helper functions of the same name.
Private member functions are a bit more visible. If they don't operate on class members, make them static.
I fully agree with your last concern: by all means: refactor.

Answer (score 1):

I'd point you at the refactoring books - especially Martin Fowler's Refactoring, and Joshua Kerievsky's Refactoring to Patterns. This problem is explored at some depth in those books.

The "stand-alone" option you describe is often called "helper methods"; there's nothing inherently wrong with this, except that they often explode into becoming the core of the method, and this leads to dependency explosion.

Private (static) methods are best if the code is directly related to the duties of the class in question.

Leaving it as is can be okay - but there's a fairly well-understood correlation between the complexity of a method and the likelihood it contains bugs. If this is a living code base, I'd refactor it.